# Javascript code instead of requested page

Tags: web-browser, javascript

I am trying to access a third party website. For one of the requests, the browser displays some source code instead of rendering the response. Does this come under security issue? The source code has a for loop and business logic inside the loop.

Comment: If Javascript is displayed  as code in the browser (instead of executed in the browser) this is likely a misconfiguration and not a security issue. But there are too few details in your question (and no way to reproduce what you see) to know for sure.

Comment: This also depends if it's actually JavaScript you see, and we don't know whether you are able to distinguish between programming languages. Displaying JavaScript instead of interpreting it as a JavaScript is not a security issue, but if the web server sends you server side source code like PHP, this might become a high risk security issue. Not to you, though, but for the site itself.

Comment: What I am getting is a for loop and json response with some fields (doesn't seem to be secure fields). Looks like json response is not interpreted correctly.